# Apply new speed to an object

Tags: javascript

I have this code which is a bouncing ball that I can move with a mouse and it is supposed to work like a slingshot. The problems are: By dragging the ball I change ball speed to mouse speed but it happens even when I click blank space. Also the speed I get from the mouse is somehow not the one with which i move my mouse.  How do I change speed only when I hold the ball and calculate the speed of the whole mouse move?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var ballRadius = 30;
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;
    var w=myCanvas.width;
    var h=myCanvas.height;
    var isDrag=false;
    var offset={x:0,y:0};   
    var totalX = 0;
    var totalY = 0;
    var moveX = 0;
    var moveY = 0;
    function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
       circle(x,y,ballRadius,'#c1153e');;
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    setInterval(draw, 15);  
    function circle(x,y,ballRadius,color='black'){
         ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h) 
         ctx.fillStyle=color;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
         ctx.fill();
     }
     circle(x,y,ballRadius,'#c1153e');
     myCanvas.onmousedown=function(e){
         var m=get_mouse_coords(e);
         circle(x,y,ballRadius,'green');
         if ((x-m.x)*(x-m.x)+(y-m.y)*(y-m.y)<ballRadius*ballRadius){
             isDrag=true;
             circle(x,y,ballRadius,'red');
             offset.x=x-m.x;
             offset.y=y-m.y;
             x=m.x+offset.x;
             y=m.y+offset.y;
         }  
     }
     function get_mouse_coords(e){
         var m={};
         var rect=myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
         m.x=e.clientX-rect.left;
         m.y=e.clientY-rect.top;
         //console.log(m);
         return m;
     }
     myCanvas.onmousemove=function(e){
        var m=get_mouse_coords(e); 
        if (isDrag) {
        x=m.x;
        y=m.y;      
             x=m.x+offset.x;
             y=m.y+offset.y;
         circle(x,y,ballRadius,'red');      
        }
     }
     myCanvas.onmouseup=function(e){
        var m=get_mouse_coords(e);
        isDrag=false;
        dx=-totalX/300;
        dy=-totalY/300;
        circle(x,y,ballRadius);
     }
     
     var totalX = 0;
    var totalY = 0;
    var moveX = 0;
    var moveY = 0;

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){
        totalX += Math.abs(ev.movementX);
        totalY += Math.abs(ev.movementY);
        moveX += ev.movementX;
        moveY += ev.movementY;
    }, false);

    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(`Speed X: ${totalX}px/s, Y: ${totalY}px/s`);
        console.log(`Movement X: ${moveX}px/s, Y: ${moveY}px/s`);
        moveX = moveY = totalX = totalY = 0;
    }, 10000);
     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the event onmouseup is executed even if you clicked in blank space, you should probably check also that isDrag is true.
Secondly, I am not sure to understand what you want to do exactly,  but should you not set the speed of your ball to zero when you click on it? Otherwise the ball is still moving even if your mouse isn't.